# Why does my score add more than one point at a time

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm having an issue when the player(Rectangle) intersects the line it adds the score more than one time. Instead of like the game flappy bird as where you get to the middle of the pipes and it counts one point each pass. I always have an issue with setting the score up correctly, not sure if it needs to be in a local variable or a global variable if it even matters? When the player passes through it will go score(1, 2, 3...10) then stop once the line comes back around it goes score(10, 11, 12...20) instead of score(1), score(2) ect..

```
public void update() {
    
    barrier.update();
    player.update();
    
    scorePoint();
}

public boolean scorePoint() {
    if (player.getBounds().intersectsLine(barrier.xPos, barrier.y - barrier.speed, 
          barrier.xPos + barrier.xWidthPos, barrier.y - barrier.speed)) {
        score += 1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are scoring a point for the same line, for every frame that the player stays intersecting the line. You will need some way of only rewarding the player once per line.

Comment: But it has to be updated so how can it update and only add one point?

Comment: That's your problem to solve - there are various ways of doing it, for example you could mark the obstacle somehow as having been "scored" already and check if it has not been scored yet before scoring it.

Comment: adding onto kaya3, you could use something like a variable to show the last scored coordinates and only score it once. or if you have an object like the flappy bird pipe, it could have a boolean variable that represents score.

Comment: or a boolean variable to represent scoring. then if scoring is false, when player intersects line, change to true and then increment score. while scoring is true and intersects, do nothing. once player does not intersect line, return variable to false. Many options, up to your implementation

Comment: Got it figured out, used a sperate timer instead of the main game-loop to determine the time between each point. Thank you for the response that gave me a better idea and understanding of how to do it.